# Can't get two block elements on one line despite display:inline-block

Tags: css

I would like to get two elements in one line (an anchor wrapped inside a div and a h3)

```
<div class="cb_inline_block">
  <div><a class="btn right-margin" href="/"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i></a></div>
  <h3>Test</h3>
</div>


.cb_inline_block {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work though,what am I missing?
I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/Kbe6P/

Answer (score 1):

Updated.. U need set the property for each element you want to display as inline-block.

```
.cb_inline_block * {
    display:inline-block;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kbe6P/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `display: inline-block;` to the actual elements you want to sit side-by-side. In this case, that's the children of `.cb_inline_block`, e.g.

```
.cb_inline_block > div,
.cb_inline_block > h3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Note that `inline-block` is whitespace sensitive, so you might need to remove the line break and spaces in the HTML between `</div>` and `<h3>`.